# How to indicate possessiveness of a noun of unknown plurailty

Tags: possessives

I am writing about the review process for scholarly publications. In this, I am trying to indicate the opinion of one or more reviewers. I could write "The opinion of the reviewer(s)" to convey that one or more reviewer may hold a specific idea.

If I were to use a possessive "'s" would it be "reviewer(s)'s opinion"?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use for multiple reviewers, and respecting their individuality:

*The opinion **of each reviewer** **was** very useful to me.* [more personal, but longish]

***Each*** **reviewer's opinion** **was** very useful to me. [personal, too]

*Each **reviewer opinion** **was** very useful to me.* [a bit more impersonal]

Now, in a more collective manner:

*All of the **reviewers' opinions** **were** very useful to me.*

which seems more personal to me than:

*All of the **reviewer opinions** **were** very useful to me.*

but it's your call.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "[according to] reviewer opinions" where "reviewer" is adjectivised. Or stick to the former option: "the opinion of the reviewer(s)".